# The requested resource (/BulkAccess/Download) is not available

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to download excel file from server after clicking on a link. I have written the below JSP and Servlet code. JSP and Servlet are both in the same folder. I get the error "`The requested resource (/BulkAccess/Download) is not available`" after clicking on hyperlink to download the excel file.

JSP Page

```
  <body>

  <a href="Download"> Sample Excel File </a>

  </body>
```

Servlet

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Download extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String filename = "C:\\excelFile.xls";


        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.addHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + filename);

        int octet;
        while((octet = in.read()) != -1)
            out.write(octet);

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }
}
```

I have the mapping in web.xml. below is the code.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.abc.bulk.Download</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Download</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Download</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have problem in calling Servlet.

This should work.

```
 <a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Download"> Sample Excel File </a>
```

Also, You have mentioned

> JSP and Servlet are both in the same folder

Generally, JSP goes under `/webapp` or `/WebContent` and Servlets goes under `/src/mypackage`.

Unrelated to the question: Its a good practice to use lowercase URL mapping.

Comment: hi, I tried the above code and it didn't work first. However, I created a new project in Eclipse and the same code with your suggestions worked. But it is not working in my original project.

Comment: @naveenkumar: Always provide details. "it didn't work" does not help you or the person who is trying to help. Provide more details about original project in the question.

Comment: Apologizes. It is giving the same error as I mentioned above.

Comment: What is name of you application ?  Is it "BulkAccess" ?

Comment: @ Hardik Mishra.. Yes  to your question.